# while using Postman tool to run collection is there any way so that there no need to capture cookies every time

Tags: web-services, rest, api, soapui, postman

while using Postman tool to run collection for authentication purpose i am using cookie,I need to capture the cookies every time i want to run the collection,Is there any way so that there no need to capture cookies every time?

Comment: What do you mean by `to run collection`?

Comment: I have created a test folder where all the test cases are present and i can run the folder to run all the test cases at once.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, you can achieve this through environment variables.
Just create an empty environment and set an environment variable like this in your test ore pre-request script:

```
    var cookievalue = responseCookies.value;
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("cookievalueyouwanttostorekey", cookievalue);
```

or

```
    var cookievalue = postman.getResponseCookie("key").value;
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("cookievalueyouwanttostorekey", cookievalue);
```

In your request, you set the JSON or parm to

```
    {{cookievalueyouwanttostorekey}}
```

Afterward, the value is present in your environment.
In the Postman Collection Runner select your created environment, and you don't have to load each time.
And put "item" in which your request is, to the first position or simply set the next request like this:

```
    postman.setNextRequest("your desired request name");
```

Comment: @MadhusudhanR please be more specific what you want to achieve and what is wrong with the answer

Comment: I am capturing cookies every time i want to send a request.
I am basically logiin in to the URL using username/password and then I press F12 by which i get Cookies(JsessonID)
Then I pass this JsessionID in the postman Tool(I navigate to Headers there I pass key as Cookie and values will be JsessionID that is captured).
Then I Build a GET Request by passing End point URL and Click on Send 
At last I get the the JSON Output

Comment: Now my Question is  if I have to repeat the testing tomorrow I have to again capture the Cookies,so do we have any alternative method where I will not have to capture the cookies every next day i will have to execute my cases.

Comment: If you have question please let me know

Comment: @MadhusudhanR please update your post with the details in the comments and provide a link for your postman collection